# Change Image Date on Google+

Tags: google-plus, images

I've uploaded some images to an album on Google+, however the camera which the photos were taken on did not have the correct date/time. Therefore my images appear out of order (as they are displayed by date).

Is there a way of changing the date/time of an image once it has been uploaded to Google+?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: since May 2014 it is now possible to [edit the date and time for individual photos on Google+](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2014/06/update-edit-photo-date-and-time.html).

> By heading to the photo details pane in the lightbox, you'll notice
>   that the data next to "Date taken" is now clickable. When pressed, you
>   are greeted with a popup in which you can edit the date and time
>   stored in the photo's metadata.
>
> [image]

[image]

---

Otherwise you can use [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/): https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/160761?hl=en

> You can use Picasa to adjust the date and time of your photos and
>   videos. Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Select the photos that you'd like to adjust. You can only adjust photos or videos from  one folder or album at a time.
> 2. In Picasa, click Tools > Adjust date and time.
> 3. In the 'New photo date:' section, enter the new date and time. If adjusting multiple photos at once, choose whether you'd like to adjust
>      all photo dates by the same amount of time or set them all to the
>      exact same date and time.
> 4. Click OK to finish.

[image]

Comment: it _is_ possible in G+, see my answer

Comment: @törzsmókus It is a new feature that did not exist at the time I wrote the answer Change Image Date on Google+ (http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2014/06/update-edit-photo-date-and-time.html)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you *can* do it from Google+:
Click on *Photo details*, then on the date/time (2nd row)

[image: edit photo date and time in G+]

Comment: the wording of my answer is a reaction to the other answer that used to be  telling that this is impossible in G+.